# Why did the Jews turn away from the promised land even though Egypt was hardly a challenge?

Tags: eretz-yisrael, egypt

As I understand, they received substantial help from God in the form of plagues, etc, so after the defeat of the immensely powerful Egyptian empire, why did they not think the same would happen with Israel?

Comment: Can you please explain when the Jews turned away from the promised land - preferably with a reference to a Biblical verse.

Answer (score 1):

The commentators deal with this issue. The Bnai Yisrael as newly freed slaves were basically infants with the implications and behaviors that immaturity brings. I go into some detail at [Beshalach: Why Israel sinned in the desert - childishness and immaturity.](http://sabbahillel.blogspot.com/2012/04/beshalach-why-israel-sinned-in-desert.html)

> The commentators have been pointing out that בני ישראל are compared to
>   children when they went into the desert after the Exodus. Many, Jews
>   and nonJews, religious and nonreligious, have used this analogy to
>   explain what happened. In fact, that is why the term used is always
>   translated as "Children of Israel".
>
> As Yirmiyahu says in [Chapter 2 pasuk 2](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15999#showrashi=true&v=2)
>
> ב  הָלֹךְ וְקָרָאתָ בְאָזְנֵי יְרוּשָׁלִַם לֵאמֹר, כֹּה אָמַר יְהוָה, זָכַרְתִּי לָךְ חֶסֶד נְעוּרַיִךְ, אַהֲבַת
>   כְּלוּלֹתָיִךְ לֶכְתֵּךְ אַחֲרַי בַּמִּדְבָּר, בְּאֶרֶץ לֹא זְרוּעָה
>
> 2: Go, and cry in the ears of Jerusalem, saying: Thus saith the LORD: I
>   remember for thee the affection of thy youth, the love of
>   thine espousals; how thou wentest after Me in the wilderness, in a
>   land that was not sown.
>
> For example, Dennis Prager, a modern radio talk show host used this
>   analogy in 1996 to explain why the Exodus is unique. Only then did
>   Hashem actively and obviously intervene on a national level with open
>   miracles in this way. Even the open miracles of the desert and the
>   miracles in the time of Yehoshua can be connected to this. All other
>   miracles were either hidden or individual. Even the miracle of the
>   altar of Elijah was relatively restricted and for a specific
>   circumstance. Actually, the fact that the sacrifice was burnt by "the
>   fire of Hashem" was considered a normal response by a "god" rather
>   than a miracle. Similarly, the sins of the Bnei Yisroel in the desert
>   from the beginning to through the  חטא העל (Golden Calf) can be
>   attributed to the fact that as newly freed slaves they were indeed
>   immature "children". Indeed, the חטא המרגלים (sin of the Spies) can be
>   considered in the same way as an expression of childishness. The
>   punishment for that can therefore be considered a necessity of our
>   having to mature before we could progress to the next stage.

Comment: Immature as they were, they defeated Egypt. I doubt they dropped in maturity during the trek

Comment: @DmitryNarkevich Actually, they did not defeat Egypt. Hashem defeated Egypt and brought them out. As freed slaves, they kept panicking whenever anything went wrong. Consider what happened when they saw Egypt coming after them at the Yam Suf or what happened on the way to Sinai (when the water was bitter). Consider why Hashem did not take them directly up the coastal highway (*Derech Eretz P'lishtim*)

Comment: @DmitryNarkevich Also the way they left Egypt at the beginning of *B'shalach* is also a sign of immaturity. They went boasting and waving their weapons even though they had not defeated Egypt and were not (yet) fit to fight a war. Even when they later fought Amalek on the way to Sinai, they needed the help of Hashem. In fact the fighting was aresult of their breaking and running to get to the water of the well at Refidim rather than continuing to march as a unified camp.